# Error loading preferences ANDROID emulator on intelj last version

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I'm getting the following error message: Error loading preferences.

on a previous version of intelj i didn't get that error i searched all over internet nobody has answer.

Update:finally it's Android SDK devices which do not create any more.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest deleting the project and create a new one. If it persists, uninstall IntelliJ and reinstall it.

Comment: finally it's Android SDK devices which do not create any more